# SQL Left Join Query to match all restriction from result

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m trying to filter data with some categories where i get a result matching *all* given slug / type parameteres.
Currently i got stuck with extendending my current query to get the data with a single query. My current query looks like that:

```
SELECT t.slug, tc.t_id, tc.c_id 
  FROM tc 
LEFT JOIN t ON t.id = tc.t_id 
WHERE 
  (t.type = 'offerAges' AND t.slug = '14-16') 
  OR 
  (t.type = 'offerSportTypes' AND t.slug = 'football')
```

Gives me following result:

```
#   slug        t_id    c_id    
1   football    13      40
2   14-16       28      39
3   14-16       28      40
```

The result i want is that i just get the results where t_id AND c_id are matching. For example in my table the items 1 & 3.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vQUU9C9iXj4gotE7YGDq6W/1

Comment: Can you explain why *t_id AND c_id* are matching in rows 1 and 3?

Comment: Should matching. I´m searching for c_ids that have 'football' AND '14-16'

Comment: The relation is `t.id = tc.t_id` so why you want to exclude the row: `14-16       28      39`

Comment: because it doesn´t match 14-16 and football. I know that the OR includes it, but and AND between that won´t give me the data, too. I dont say that the current query is partly the one it should be, but it is the one i just got stuck with 'almost' nearly at the data i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  In this case:

```
SELECT tc.c_id 
FROM tc JOIN
     t
     ON t.id = tc.t_id 
WHERE (t.type = 'offerAges' AND t.slug = '14-16') OR 
      (t.type = 'offerSportTypes' AND t.slug = 'football')
GROUP BY tc.c_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.type) = 2;
```

If you want the slugs, I would recommend using `GROUP_CONCAT()` to put them in a single column:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(t.slug)
```

Comment: When using group by nothing changes / having has no result. I added an Fiddle

Comment: @develth . . . You seem to only want the `c_id`s that match.